# PowerQuery table refresh stops with an error

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have experienced several time situation where using power query and refreshing large table (~300K rows) it stops loading rows with an error:

> Error Message:
>
> The MashupResource's PageReader is not available.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: The MashupResource's PageReader is
>   not available.    at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.FillManager.RefreshFillSession.GetSchemaInfo()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.FillManager.RefreshFillSession.CompleteRefresh(IWorkbook
>   workbook, Boolean onTimer)    at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.FillManager.RefreshFillSession.UpdateRefreshStatus(IWorkbook
>   workbook, Boolean onTimer)    at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.FillManager.RefreshFillSession.ResumeFill(Boolean
>   onTimer)    at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.FillManager.UpdateQueries()    at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.FillManager.b__5()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler
>   exceptionHandler, Action action)
>
> Invocation Stack Trace:
>
> at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionExtensions.GetCurrentInvocationStackTrace()
>   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.ClientShared.StackTraceInfo..ctor(String
>   exceptionStackTrace, String invocationStackTrace)    at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Client.ClientShared.ErrorDetails..ctor(String
>   message, Nullable`1 errorCode, String requestId, Exception exception) 
>   at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Client.ClientShared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.SynchronizationContextExtensions.Send(SynchronizationContext
>   context, IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action callback)    at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Client.ClientShared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception
>   e)    at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler
>   exceptionHandler, Action action)    at
>   Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.FillManager.OnFillUpdateTimerTick(Object
>   sender, EventArgs eventArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg,
>   IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>
> MashupResource.Status Initializing

I get this error when some table is refreshing and I try to use other excel file. Do anyone have an idea what does it mean? I have tried searching it in google with no success.

I am using Excel 2010 32bit, version 14.0.7015.1000 and PowerQuery version 2.27.4163.242

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? If you're using 2010 or 2013, what version of Power Query are you using?

Comment: @AlejandroLopez-Lago-MSFT I have updated question with versions of excel and PowerQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry you ran into this problem, the message indicates there's some bug in Power Query.

If you could try upgrading to the latest public Power Query (we're at version 2.30 now) does the problem go away?

If not, it might be easiest to Send a Frown from the error prompt and you can get in touch with our super-helpful support team?

Comment: After updating to version 2.30 I cannot recreate this error, so I guess this is solved, thanks!

Comment: I still get this error on version 2.49 (Power Query -> File -> Options and settings -> Query Options -> Diagnostics)

Comment: @racitup IIRC we think we fixed the original issue, so this might be a new bug. Does the error happen often, or one time? Either way, the best way to report it is to send-a-frown (ideally from the error dialog), and to ask a new question tagged powerquery :)