# How to avoid Power Query error with empty query from VBA Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, text-files, powerquery, can-bus

I would like to import a text file into Excel filtering just what I want through a VBA macro. The amount of data is large so I use efficently the Power queries. I have a list of several things to filter and process differently and this list could change. So for each "feature" to filter I reload the query in a new sheet.
If the filter makes the query empty I get an error from the Power Query that I am not able to skip with:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

[image: Power query error]

Debugging I see that the error comes out between the query creation and the paste to the sheet, see (*) in the code below.

Does somebody know if there is a way to have the number of records into the query in order to be able to use an if statement and skip the paste phase?

The only other idea that I have is to write automatically a row for each feature into the txt file to filter but it is not an elegant method

A thing that I do not understand is that the problem appear using a function, see below, but not using directly a macro.
When I use the function the error shown does not appear always but in any case the code finish the function but the main macro stops.

test.txt

```
946737295   9CE78280    FF  1   5   FF  FF  FF  FF  FF
946737295   9CE78280    C0  FF  0   0   0   0   FF  FF
946737295   9CE68082    C0  4   0   FF  FF  FF  FF  FF
```

and the macro is:

```
Function readTxt(input_path As String, Pgn As String, B2 As String, B3 As String) As Boolean

    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Conn As WorkbookConnection
    Dim mFormula As String
    Dim query As WorkbookQuery
    
    Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Ws = Wb.ActiveSheet
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       

    mFormula = "let " & _
        "Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""" & input_path & """),[Delimiter=""#(tab)"", Columns=10, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.Csv])," & _
        "#""Step1"" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each Text.Contains([Column2], """ & Pgn & """) and [Column5] = """ & B3 & """ and [Column4] = """ & B2 & """)," & _
        "#""Step2"" = Table.RemoveColumns(Step1,{""Column2"", ""Column3"", ""Column4"", ""Column5"", ""Column9"", ""Column10""})" & _
        "in #""Step2"""
    
    Set query = Wb.Queries.Add("test_7", mFormula)

    With Ws.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
         "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & "test_7" & ";Extended Properties=""""", Destination:=Ws.Range("A3"), XlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes).QueryTable
         '.ListObject.TotalsRowRange
         .CommandType = xlCmdSql
         .AdjustColumnWidth = False
         .ListObject.Name = "test"
         .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" & "test_7" & "]" 
         .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
     End With
         
     If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Err.Clear
     End If
      
      query.Delete
         
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    readTxt = True 'output
    
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

```
Sub readTxt()
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim Conn As WorkbookConnection
Dim mFormula As String
Dim query As WorkbookQuery

Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook

Dim i As Integer
Dim C3 As String

    On Error Resume Next
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

C3 = "F2"

For i = 1 To 2
       
    If i = 2 Then
        C3 = "FF"
        Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    End If
    Set Ws = Wb.ActiveSheet

    mFormula = "let " & _
        "Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""C:\test.txt""),[Delimiter=""#(tab)"", Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.Csv])," & _
        "#""Step1"" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each Text.Contains([Column2], ""E7"") and [Column3] = """ & C3 & """)" & _
        "in #""Step1"""
        
    Set query = Wb.Queries.Add("Test_text", mFormula)
    
    ' (*) THE ERROR OF POWER QUERY APPEARS HERE
    
    With Ws.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
         "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & "Test_text" & ";Extended Properties=""""", Destination:=Ws.Range("A3"), XlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes).QueryTable
         .CommandType = xlCmdSql
         .AdjustColumnWidth = False
         .ListObject.Name = "test"
         .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" & "Test_text" & "]"
         .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
     End With
     
     query.Delete
 
Next

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    On Error GoTo 0
      
End Sub
```

Thanks,
Ruggero

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you're saying the error raises when there's no data in the txt file?

Comment: Code is working for me with the example provivded. Query does not return any data as the filter you add in the second step returns an empyt table. And that's what I get in the excel sheet as well. Code also works for an empty text file. Maybe behaviour is version dependant.

Comment: Thanks, have you tried a step with data after the one without data? For example a sheet with `[Column3] = ""F1""` and a second one with  `[Column3] = ""FF""`

Comment: Why should I? You provided the M-Code, so I took that. And you are saying you get the error with the code above, aren't you? BTW, I got version2.86.725.0 32-bit of PQ.

Comment: I edited the code to be more clear but in this way it seems to work. Actually I am using this code inside a function, I try to load that

Comment: The error messagge into the details is "The MashupResource's PageReader is not available". Power Query 2.78.5740.481 64bit

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a step (table) has some specific columns using this code:

```
let Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\temp\test.txt"),[Delimiter=";", Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.Csv]),
    #"Step1" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each Text.Contains([Column2], "E7") and [Column3] = "F1"),
    result_error = "Some error",
    check_columns = Table.HasColumns(#"Step1", {"Column2", "Column3"}),
    result = if check_columns = true then #"Step1" else result_error
in result
```

See the check_columns step and the conditional result

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, it could be useful for another check that I could have to do. In the described case I have more or less always the same columns, but the rows are 0 in some cases

Comment: I’m not at my desk right now, but following the same logic, use Table.RowCount function

Comment: I tried with Table.RowCount and it works to have at least a line but the code still stop. I saw that the problem appears also with other keys for the fileter. Reading another thread I understand that could be a bug related to the big dimension of the txt. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36620810/powerquery-table-refresh-stops-with-an-error) _italic_ **bold** 
The error messagge into the details is "The MashupResource's PageReader is not available". Power Query 2.78.5740.481 64bit

Comment: Maybe provide a link to the txt sample file that has all the columns

Comment: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/el7vofkj6f7y2z4/test_9.TXT?dl=0) to txt 30Mb file, the macro above gives the error: "The MashupResource's PageReader is not available" and the `F2` is empty altough there are data

Comment: No problem on my side with the 30MB file. Are you using what version on Excel 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Excel 16.0.12527.21296 64bit
Power Query 2.78.5740.481 64bit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224928/discussion-between-ruggero-bini-and-ricardo-diaz).